# How do I delete an icon from the desktop but keep it on the launcher?

Tags: icons, delete

I installed steam and the program created two icons one in the launcher and one on the desktop.

When I try to delete the one on the desktop, the other one  is also deleted. I only want to keep the one on the launcher.

I'm a first time user of Ubuntu (12.04) and it seems confusing sometimes. If you can help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The launcher files are located in `/usr/share/applications`. It seems that *steam* created a hard-link between your desktop and launcher file. You will need to split them up.

```
sudo su
cd /usr/share/applications
cp <file> <file.temp>
```

The `<file>` is the *steam* .desktop file - since I don't know how it's called you have to look for yourself.
Now you can delete the desktop file and the file in `/usr/share/applications` should also be gone. Rename the temp file to its original name and you should have what you wanted.

```
mv <file.temp> <file>
```